# assistance needed constructing JSONata query

Tags: jsonata

I am trying to construct a JSONata query using the try.jsonata.org Invoice data.

The query I am trying to pose is `select distinct OrderID where Order.Product.Price is < 50?`

I have not been able to figure out how to do this using the *predicate in square brackets* notation ... my attempts have been thwarted when I try to get past the $.Account.Order.Product array.

Using $map and $reduce I was able to come up with [this rather complex solution](http://try.jsonata.org/rJNsgQNoG) ... which still doesn't correctly handle duplicate OrderIDs. (I see that the issue of duplicate removal has been requested [here](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/117))

Q: What is the proper way to express this query in JSONata?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://try.jsonata.org/SJuZ1pVoM) does what you need:

```
Account.Order[Product.Price.($ < 50)].OrderID
```

The expression in the predicate, which gets tested for each `Order`, will generate an array of Booleans (one for each `Product.Price`).  The resulting predicate will evaluate to `true` if any of the Booleans within that array are `true`, due to the semantics of the [`$boolean` function](http://docs.jsonata.org/boolean-functions.html#booleanarg) which is implicitly applied.

Overall, the expression will return the `OrderID` for every `Order` which has at least one `Product` whose `Price` is less than `50`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I will need to spend some time reading through your explanation of boolean behavior.

Comment: I have spent some time playing around in order to better understand the query predicate behavior. [This](http://try.jsonata.org/B1xxykSif) is an alternate syntax which seems to accomplish the same thing. [This](http://try.jsonata.org/rky9JJSsM) is the same thing, with explicit calls `$boolean()`

Comment: Yep, predicate within a predicate - that's clearer I think.